# development is x pull requests behind

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request

I moved our source to git (vso) recently. But i can not understand how the pullrequests are supposed to work.

Here is what we have:
we have a remote master and development branch, and we all do only check into the development branch. After the CI build I the author creates a pull request and somebody confirms it. Now i would expect visual studio on the Branch page to show that the two branches are on the same state 0 behind/0 ahead but actually after every successful pull request my dev branch is behind (1 per accepted pull request)

What does that mean, why are my branches not on the same state after pulling all commits from dev to main.

Answer (score 1):

After a successful pull request, the master branch will create a new commit named "Merge pull request *x* from *branch* into master" as well as the commit in dev branch, that's why your dev branch is 1 commit behind of the master branch. You can find the difference by checking commits history for each branch after a successful pull request.

If you fetch master branch, merge it to dev branch, and push to VSO, your branches will have the same state.

Comment: I'm currently having this problem but can't push my merge directly to dev as there is a policy that requires a pull request. Is there another way to do this?